# ttf mscorefonts installer

Tags: fonts

I followed instructions on a previous post about installing mscorefonts which I did on the terminal and accepted the license terms. However after rebooting I get the same failure message about the fonts not installing?  How can I check they are installed or alternatively remove the error message? thanks

Comment: And what is "the same failure message" supposed to be? Can we know the exact error or is it a secret?

Comment: Data files for some packages could not be downloaded

The following packages requested additional data downloads after package installation, but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed.

ttf-mscorefonts-installer

This is a permanent failure that leaves these packages unusable on your system.  You may need to fix your Internet connection, then remove and reinstall the packages to fix this problem.

Comment: I have just posted the "error" message which I get, I rebooted the pc and still got it. I will also shortly post the output from the terminal, asI think it is saying that the fonts are installed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the package is installed with this command:

```
dpkg -l ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: philip@philip-Aspire-E1-571:~$ dpkg -l ttf-mscorefonts-installer Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad) ||/ Name             Version       Architecture  Description +++-================-=============-=============-===================================== ii  ttf-mscorefonts- 3.4+nmu1ubunt all           Installer for Microsoft TrueType core philip@philip-Aspire-E1-571:~$

Comment: I have posted the string from the terminal, it seems to me like the fonts are installed?

Comment: Yes, In your output the "ii" means that the package is install.